# Profile2 Registration Path loose registration field after translate URL alias

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n

I use Profile2 and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module. [This](http://www.bo-medical.com/doctor/register) is the original `Registration Path`, set in the configuration.

I tried to translate the `Registration Path` at `Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases`.

But when i visit for example the [Belgium dutch](http://www.bo-medical.com/benl/dokter/registreer) version, i loose my extra added Profile field at my Registration form (RIZIV number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profile2 Registration Path module does not support multilingual URL aliases. Profile2 fields are added to reg form based on the alias that you set up on profile2 edit form. That is why your profile2 fields are not displayed on dutch version of reg form. Your best choice is to remove translated alias and set your original regpath alias to something that sounds good in both languages. Or you can improve the module by adding multilingual alias support (though it may require some reworking in module's logic).

Comment: thanks. And is there any other module same like Profile2 where you can translate the aliases?

Comment: as of today - no